# Should broadcast intents be defined in Producer's namespace?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

App A fires-off a Broadcast intent which is received by App B, C and D. Should the intent action be defined in App A's namespace? 
If the Java package name of App A  is com.a and Java package of B is com.b, I think the Intent Action should be something like com.a.SOMETHING. What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the intent action be defined in App A's namespace?

Probably. IMHO, `Intent` actions should be namespaced for whatever "owns" the actions:

- If Apps A-D are written by the same developer, App A would seem to "own" the action, simply because it's the one doing the broadcasting
- If Apps A-D are written as part of a consortium, the consortium would seem to "own" the action, and so the action would be namespaced based on the consortium (e.g., based off of their domain name)
- If Apps A-D are written by developers looking to adhere to some convention or standard, the "owner" is effectively the convention or standard, and so the action would be namespaced based on that standard (e.g., based off of the domain name of the Web site that documents the proposed standard)
- If Apps A-D are written by unaffiliated independent developers, App A would seem to "own" the action, simply because it's the one doing the broadcasting